# I got a problem in removeRole in the discord.js timed mute command (removeRole is not a function)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

the remove role error
my code:

```
    bot.on('message', message => {
    let prefix = "t?";

    let args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");

    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'mute':
        let person = message.mentions.users.first(); message.guild.members.fetch(args[1])
        if(!person) return message.reply("couldnt find member");

        let mainrole = message.guild.fetch(role => role.name === "member");
        let muterole = message.guild.fetch(role => role.name === "muted");

        if(!muterole) return message.reply("couldn't find mute role");

        let time = (args[2]);

        if(!time) {
            return message.reply("how long? <:Thonk:582005026470363137>");
        }

        person.removeRole(mainrole.id);
        person.addRole(muterole.id);

        channel.send(`@${person.user.tag} has now been muted for ${ms(ms(time))}`);

        setTimeout(function(){
            person.addRole(mainrole.id);
            person.removeRole(muterole.id);
            message.channel.send(`@${person.user.tag} has been unmuted.`);
        }, ms(time));




        break;
    }
});
```

and it pops up and error that says remove Role is not a function
do anyone know how to solve these kinds of problem in discord

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/11.5.1/class/GuildMember) with [User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/11.5.1/class/User).

A user is a person on Discord, a GuildMemebr is a person on discord as pertaining to a specific guild.  For example, you can DM a user or a guild member because direct messages don't have anything to do with guilds, but you can't remove a role from a user because a user isn't associated with a guild, there are no roles to remove.

So, you need to get `message.mentions.members` not `message.mentions.users`

The documentation for this is here in [MessageMentions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/11.5.1/class/MessageMentions)